# When will SPFx native classes support OAuth2 code flow with PKCE?

Tags: spfx, oauth, access-token

Does Microsoft have any plans to update native SharePoint Framework classes to replace the OAuth2 implicit flow by the code flow with PKCE, for obtaining access tokens from Azure AD?